# How to iterate through kendo datasoure on view

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm using the kendo core ui (free version) and I'm not sure what I need to do in my view in order to iterate through the data...Honestly, I'm not sure what to even look for. I tried using a template but couldn't get it to work. I'd like to display the data in a table. Here is my view model.

```
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
          read: {
              url: '/Customer/GetCustomers',
              dataType: 'json'
          }
       }
     });
     dataSource.read();
     var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        title: 'Current Customers',
        AllCustomers: dataSource,

     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was making things way more difficult than what they needed to be. I was trying to apply a 'for' loop within my template but it was not needed.

This works correctly now.

**HTML**

```
<table data-bind="source: AllCustomers" data-template="template"></table>
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr>
        <td>#: CompanyName #</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax("/Customer/GetCustomers", {

    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        viewModel.set("AllCustomers", result);
    }
});

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    title: 'Current Customers',
    AllCustomers: null
});
```